# Laravel Database Connection Error Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have the problem with database connection after i ran a migration which is Illuminate\Database\QueryException. I've tried to ran the "php artisan migrate:fresh" command, but it didn't work. What should I do? Thanks in advance.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etiMX.png)

Comment: maybe you can try to delete your database and make a new one, then run the migration again

Comment: I've tried this one.  But, it produced the same error @AdhiArdiansyah

Comment: can you show your migration code?

Comment: Schema::table('congregations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('national_family_card_image', 255)->after('image');
        });

Answer (score 0):

Check your php path in environment variables, php path must be of XAMP i.e "***C:\xampp\php***". Set this and then try to migrate again

Answer (score 0):

Go to PHP.ini file and watch for

```
extension_dir
```

It should be aligned with the php version of your project

```
extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\ext"
```

So its `php version 8` for you